# Generating language from grammar

Tags: logic, linguistics

To be concrete, consider the following formal grammar:
$$S \rightarrow aSb$$
$$S \rightarrow \varepsilon$$

The language generated by this grammar is $L = \{ a^n b^n | n \geq 0 \}$. How can I implement this grammar and ask Mathematica to compute its corresponding language? Thanks!

EDIT: I don't want to implement this grammar from scratch, using basic functionalities in Mathematica. I'm looking for Mathematica functions designed to deal with this problem.

Comment: And what kind of mathematical apparatus is used to formally describe grammar?

Comment: @dtn Set theory as far as I know.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't specific enough but I don't want to implement this grammar from scratch, using basic functionalities in Mathematica. I'm looking for Mathematica functions designed to deal with this problem.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProgrammableLinguisticInterface.html check out this link for some ideas and inspiration. It is possible that experts in language research will suggest more. To solve highly specialized problems, packages can be developed that can be integrated into Mathematica.In the future, you should look for them, for example, on GitHub.

Comment: You can generate random examples from your grammar very easily: `Table[
  FixedPoint[StringReplace[#,
     RandomChoice@rules] &
   , "S"],
  {50}] // DeleteDuplicates`
If you want to jump straight to the general form $a^n b^n$ then that is kind of hard. I recommend using a [program called JFLAP](https://www.jflap.org) for this which will allow you to generate regexes / pushdown automata for DFA's/NFA's / context free grammars. Here's the PDA for your one https://imgur.com/a/xBC5FPl .

Comment: @flinty I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: I don't see why this question should be closed or why it is deemed so specialized. It clearly describes what is required by using the example of a formal grammar, using the standard notation for transformation rules (S as the starting symbol, capital letters as variable symbols to be replaced, small letters as symbols making up the words of the language, and epsilon as the empty string). Then it becomes a matter of recursively applying these transformation rules as new strings are generated, extracting the words of the language (small letters only) along the way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for fun, a basic attempt at a function, with three languages used as examples:

Note that **n** is just the number of times through the loop. We could instead loop until we collect n words, but then we have to be sure that the rules do generate these words.

```
generateLanguage[start_String, terminal_List, variable_List, 
  rules_List, n_Integer] := Module[{language, running, i},
  language = {};
  running = {start};
  i = 1;
  While[i <= n,
   running = 
    Flatten@(StringReplaceList[#, rules] & /@ Flatten@running);
   If[StringCount[#, variable] == 0, AppendTo[language, #]] & /@ 
    running;
   i++;
   ];
 DeleteDuplicates@language
  ]
```

EXAMPLE 1: $L = \{ a^n b^n | n \geq 0 \}$

```
rules = {"S" :> "aSb", "S" :> ""};
startSymbol = "S";
terminal = {"a", "b"};
variable = {"S"};
generateLanguage[startSymbol, terminal, variable, rules, 14]

(* {,ab,aabb,aaabbb,aaaabbbb,aaaaabbbbb,aaaaaabbbbbb,aaaaaaabbbbbbb,aaaaaaaabbbbbbbb,aaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbb,aaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbb,aaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbb,aaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbb,aaaaaaaaaaaaabbbbbbbbbbbbb} *)
```

EXAMPLE 2: $L = \{ (a b)^n | n \geq 1 \}$

```
rules = {"S" :> "Tb", "T" :> "a", "T" :> "Sa"};
startSymbol = "S";
terminal = {"a", "b"};
variable = {"S", "T"};
generateLanguage[startSymbol, terminal, variable, rules, 15]

(* {ab,abab,ababab,abababab,ababababab,abababababab,ababababababab} *)
```

EXAMPLE 3: $L = \{ a^n b^n c^n | n \geq 1 \}$

(Slow! Keep n low)

```
rules = {"S" :> "aSTU", "S" :> "aTU", "UT" :> "TU", "aT" :> "ab", 
   "bT" :> "bb", "bU" :> "bc", "cU" :> "cc"};
startSymbol = "S";
terminal = {"a", "b", "c"};
variable = {"R", "S", "T", "U"};
generateLanguage[startSymbol, terminal, variable, rules, 12]

(* {abc,aabbcc,aaabbbccc} *)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: How did you generate these images?

Comment: I made these images a few years ago for some common, specific languages, using the function ```Graph[]``` and manually entering the details.  I added these here so people unfamiliar with the process could see how these transformations generate specific words of the language.